# log4j new log file is not creating when tomcat 7 starting in AWS server instance

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, logging, log4j, tomcat7

I have implemented a log4j XML file to create a new log file.in my local machine, when the tomcat starts the java web application, log file is being created without any issue.but i have hosted my java web application in aws instance configured with tomcat 7.but when i logged to aws instance and check tomcat log folder grid-services.log file cannot be located.can anyone tell why this happened?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd" >
<log4j:configuration debug="false">

    <appender name="default.console" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <param name="target" value="System.out" />
        <param name="threshold" value="debug" />
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{ISO8601} %-5p [%c{1}] - %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <appender name="default.file" class="org.apache.log4j.FileAppender">
        <param name="file" value="${catalina.home}/logs/grid-services.log" />
        <param name="append" value="false" />
        <param name="threshold" value="debug" />
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{ISO8601} %-5p [%c{1}] - %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender> 

    <logger name="com.customer"
        additivity="false">
        <level value="info" />
        <appender-ref ref="default.file" />
    </logger>
    <root>
        <priority value="info" />
        <appender-ref ref="default.console" />
        <appender-ref ref="default.file" />
    </root>
</log4j:configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

Look in your ${TOMCAT_HOME}/bin/catalina.sh. Check if the

```
-Dcatalina.home=
```

variable is set on your aws instance.